# Detecting biased coins

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

**EDIT:** By detecting I mean to statistically confirm, with a certain confidence, if the coin is actually biased or not, with a particular bias of $p = 0.57$. I'd like to know what is the best way of framing this as a statistical test. I guess that the answer depends on the prior confidence that we have on the bias actually being 0.57 or not.

---

I'm interested in developing a statistical test to detect coins with a given bias, and in particular I want to specify how many coin flips are needed to detect such a biased coin.

More precisely, say we are told that a certain coin has a probability of heads $p$ equal to $0.57$, and we are asked to determine the minimum amount of coin flips such that we can confidently detect the bias. Here, confidently means with a particular significance level. There are several ways we can tackle this problem.

Using hypothesis testing, and using either the Z-test or the binomial test, we could do the following: first, one would think of a test where the null hypothesis is that the coin is fair, and the alternative is $p = 0.57$ or $p > 0.5$. The latter, $p > 0.5$, would help us in detecting if the coin is more biased towards heads, but we wouldn't be able to detect the particular bias, so putting $p = 0.57$ makes more sense. The rejection zones would be the same, but we would have a better control of the type $2$ error if we set $H_1: p = 0.57$. If $H_1: p > 0.50$, the required minimum sample size would be larger.

Since we are explicitly told that the coin has this particular bias of $p = 0.57$, it also makes sense to set $H_0: p = 0.57$, $H_1: p \neq 0.57$, set a particular significance level $\alpha$ to define our rejection zone, and then aim for a certain reduction in the probability of type $2$ error, $\beta$, and find the minimum sample size such that this reduction in $\beta$ is achieved.

Finally, another method that we could use is the following: we know that the best estimator of $p$ is the average of heads, $\widehat{p}$, that we see in a particular independent sample. Thus, we could fix a significance level $\alpha$, build a $(1 - \alpha)$-confidence interval for $p$ and determine the minimum sample size such that $\left| p - \widehat{p} \right| < \delta$, for any given maximum error $\delta$ that we are happy with. We could combine the minimum sample size we obtain from the previous test $H_0: p = 0.57$, $H_1: p \neq 0.57$ together with this new threshold.

**My questions are:**

1. Did I make any mistakes in my reasoning?
2. Among the methods that I suggested, which one is the "most appropriate" here?
3. Are there any "better" or similar methods?

Comment: it's not clear what is the objective. are you trying to confirm that the bias is in fact p=0.57? otherwise, what does "detect bias" mean?

Comment: The answer to (3) is yes, because none of your methods truly address the stated question, which is to distinguish between just *two* possible conditions.

Comment: @Aksakal Yes, the goal would be to confirm if the bias is actually $p = 0.57$ or not, and to determine the minimum number of coin flips such that we can confidently accept or reject this hypothesis. I guess that the test design would depend on the prior confidence that we have on the bias actually being 0.57 or not. If we truly believe that the bias is 0.57, it makes sense to set p = 0.57 as the null, otherwise it would make more sense to be more conservative and set p = 0.5 as the null hypothesis.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT "how many coin flips are required to establish the probability of tails is p with confidence alpha?" and got a reasonable answer. it was a Gaussian approximation to Binomial but it should work for you

Comment: Yes, in my case, ChatGPT's answer is the threshold that you obtain in the last approach I suggested. In particular, the answer is that $n >= \frac{Z^2*\sigma^2}{\delta^2}$, where $Z$ is the critical value from the standard normal distribution corresponding to the desired level of confidence, but I wanted to know if we can do better than this.

Comment: It's always gratifying to see how badly ChatGPT can screw up an answer to a simple statistical question: the singularity hasn't yet arrived... .

Answer (score 2):

The question asks us to distinguish between the possibilities $p = 0.5$ (unbiased) and $p = 0.57$ (biased) ("confirm... if the coin is actually biased or not, with a particular bias of p=0.57".)

The [Neyman-Pearson lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma) guides us on how to construct a uniformly most powerful test using the likelihood ratio, which in this case, where $p = 0.57$ is the null hypothesis, is:

$$\Lambda = { 0.57^n0.43^{N-n} \over 0.5^N} = \left({0.43 \over 0.5}\right)^N\left({0.57 \over 0.43}\right)^n$$

where $n$ is the number of heads and $N$ is the number of coin flips.

Clearly the test statistic will be $n$; the question remains, how to choose a critical value for an $\alpha-$level test?  Since, under the null hypothesis, $n \sim \mathop{Binomial}(N,0.57)$, we set the critical value $n^* =\max_n:P(n; N, 0.57) \leq \alpha$, the largest value of $n$ for which the cumulative probability of $n$ is $\leq \alpha$.

For example, for $N = 20$ and $\alpha = 0.05$, a quick calculation gives us $n^* = 7$; we reject the null hypothesis if $n \leq n^*$.

What is the power of this test?  It's the probability that we reject a false null hypothesis, in this case, $p(n; N, 0.5) \leq n^*$.   For $N=20 $ and $\alpha = 0.05$, the power is $0.13$, which is not very high, but the difference between $0.5$ and $0.57$ is small and $N$ isn't large either.

For $N = 100$ and $\alpha = 0.05$, we have $n^* = 48$ and a power of $0.38$.  At $N = 1000$, $n^* = 543$ and the power is $0.997$.  At this point, it's pretty easy to write some code iterating over $N$ to determine how large $N$ has to be to achieve a specified power; a brute force method is shown below:

```
alpha <- 0.05
tgt_power <- 0.5

for (N in 1:1000) {
  n_star <- qbinom(alpha, N, 0.57) - 1
  power <- pbinom(n_star, N, 0.5)
  if (power > tgt_power) break;
}

N
[1] 141
```

Answer (score 0):

You can never confirm the bias is exactly 0.57, but you can do enough flips to rule out other values.

The confidence interval for the binomial proportion is, at its widest,

$$ \hat{p} \pm z_{1-\alpha/2} \sqrt{\dfrac{0.25}{N}} $$

You could rule out possible biases larger than $\delta$ in either direction of $\hat{p}$ by requiring

$$z_{1-\alpha/2} \sqrt{\dfrac{0.25}{N}} \leq \delta$$

Some simple algebra shows that this means

$$ \dfrac{z_{1-\alpha/2}}{4\delta^2} \leq N $$

With this in mind, you could:

- Determine a $\delta$ of practical interest
- Set $N$ accordingly
- Compute the confidence interval for the bias
- Rule out those values outside the confidence interval as possible

As mentioned, it is impossible to confirm that the bias is 0.57, but you can perform enough flips to rule out as many alternatives as you like.

Comment: Your solution makes sense, but would you consider adding an upper bound on the type 2 error as well? I mean, the confidence interval you describe is in correspondence with an acceptance region with probability of type 1 error equal to $\alpha$, and the choice of $\delta$ controls the effect size, but it's also interesting to reduce the probability of type 2 error ($\beta$) to a certain quantity, and maybe the threshold obtained via controlling the effect size isn't enough. I would consider the threshold to be the max between this one and the one obtained by bounding $\beta$. What do you think?

Comment: @user_12345 I would approach this as an estimation problem as opposed to a hypothesis test. You can’t accept the null that the bias is 0.57, so just go ahead and estimate what the bias is to whatever precision is useful to you